# How to get JSchema to use the $schema property in a json data file for validation

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

If I have a JSON data file(not a JSON schema file) with a $schema property pointing to a valid scheme URL on the internet. How can I get the JSchema to load the schema from the URL? All the examples I've seen passes in a schema definition into JSchema.

Obviously I know I can parse the JSON data file and read the URL, then do my own WebRequest for the schema file. I'm wanting to know if that functionality is built in already?

Comment: Probably not. It's not a defined standard way to do it.

Comment: To do what? If it's not standard then why would they put the $schema property in the json definition?

Comment: Doing that is not specified by the JSON Schema specification. The source probably expect you to extract that field manually if you wish to retrieve the JSON Schema and validate the instance (data). You could ask them (as in whoever supplied you with the JSON), but I expect that's the response you would get.

Comment: I've seen the $schema property on numerous json data files along with being in the jsonschema library of newtonsoft. Not sure why it would be in either of it wasn't standard.

Comment: Here is the section in the specification on the use of `$schema`. It does not mention use in the data instance. http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.7 - Some people may have decided it could be a convention, but it's not part of the specification. Equally they could provide it in a header of an HTTP response if they so wished.

Comment: So it is in the definition then... "the location of a resource which is itself a JSON Schema, which describes any schema written for this particular version.

Comment: Nope. That means it represents the location of the JSON Schemas meta schema, should you wish to validate your JSON Schema file.

Comment: I have used several JSON editors that recognize the $schema property and validate the file against it while building it out. So... again, I have hard time not seeing it as standard somewhere, else why would a bunch of editors read it and validate with it.

Comment: Sure, I don't argue that it isn't really useful, and people have added it to their JSON data because it's a great convention, and editors may provide it by default... BUT, it is not in the JSON Schema spec, so you cannot expect clients to implement it. They may, but it's not required by the spec. (BTW, I am one of the core members that work on the spec)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the jsonschema spec, as it only relates to schema files and not data files...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. I'm happy to discuss further via the JSON Schema slack, tomorrow.

Comment: @Relequestual Are you a c# or Newtonsoft developer?